# Assigning pointer value to another pointer value. Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to assign the address of a dynamic array to another dynamic array i.e. the address of two pointers I have:

```
 Someclass *pointer = new Someclass[10];

 Someclass *pointer2 = new Someclass[10];
```

I now want to assign the address of pointer to pointer2:

```
 pointer2 = pointer;
```

Testing to see if address is same:

```
 cout << &pointer2 << endl;
 cout << &pointer << endl;
```

My output:

```
 0x28fed4
 0x28fb98
```

So their addresses are not the same. What gives? Didn't I just assign them to the same address by typing pointer2 = pointer? If not then what does this statement do?

I tried doing this with a simpler program without classes and objects:

```
 int main()
 {
int * pointer1;
int * pointer2;

pointer1 = pointer2;

cout << &pointer1 << endl;
cout << &pointer2 << endl;
}
```

And its the same, their addresses are still different? This is probably rudimentary stuff that I am misunderstanding, can someone clear it up? Thanks.

Comment: They are different objects, so their addresses are different. You have a memory leak BTW.

Comment: Try to print the with out the `&`. P.S Your avatar picture rulez!!!

Comment: If you do `int i=0; int j=1; i = j` do you expect `&i` and `&j` to become the same?

Answer (score 5):

You are printing out the *address* of the pointer, not the address the pointer is pointing to!

Try this:

```
cout << pointer2 << endl;
cout << pointer << endl;
```

When you use `&` you take the *address of* something so `&pointer` is the *address of* the pointer, not the thing it points to. Yes, even pointers can have pointers pointing to them!

Comment: Wow thank you so much I just got confused. Sorry to ask such a stupid question!

Comment: Just to be clear...the pointer has an address just like any variable, and it is also pointing to another address, and that address is the value of the pointer? Is that right? So basically a pointer can have two addresses, the one where the pointer itself is stored and the one the pointer is pointing to (unless it is a NULL pointer that is)?

Comment: Yes, but it's confusing to think that it "has two addresses". A pointer, like any variable has one address. And like other variables, it has a value. For an integer the value is a number, but for a pointer it's an address. But it doesn't have two addresses. It has one address, and it has a value (which is an address).

Comment: Thanks. I realize wording it like "it has two addresses" is confusing since it has an address like all variables where it sits in the memory but what is special about it is that its value is another address that you assign it to or 0 in case of NULL pointer. But does this mean a pointer can have the address of itself as its value? Is it possible?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard A pointer can't normally hold its own address because the type system gives it a different type (*pointer to pointer to type*). But you can wedge it in with casting. The `void*` is an exception to this and can point to itself.